# Type mismatch for function composition

Tags: scala

I have defined an identity function and a composition function:

```
def identity[T](x: T): T = x
def composition[A, B, C](f: A => B, g: B => C)(x: A) = g(f(x))
```

I am trying to assert that the identity function can be applied on both sides with the same result:

```
assert(composition((x: Int) => x + 1, identity)(3) == composition(identity, (x: Int) => x + 1)(3))
```

However, I am getting these errors:

```
Error:(7, 40) type mismatch;
 found   : Nothing => Nothing
 required: Int => Nothing
assert(composition((x: Int) => x + 1, identity)(3) == composition(identity, (x: Int) => x + 1)(3));}
```

And:

```
Error:(7, 68) type mismatch;
 found   : Nothing => Nothing
 required: A => Nothing
assert(composition((x: Int) => x + 1, identity)(3) == composition(identity, (x: Int) => x + 1)(3));}
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the case because the compiler is having difficulty inferring the types properly, specifically inferring what `A` is. You can help him by placing `A` as the first argument and each function in a separate parameter list:

```
def composition[A, B, C](x: A)(f: A => B)(g: B => C) = g(f(x))
```

And now this works as expected:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def identity[T](x: T): T = x
def composition[A, B, C](x: A)(f: A => B)(g: B => C) = g(f(x))

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

identity: [T](x: T)T
composition: [A, B, C](x: A)(f: A => B)(g: B => C)C

scala> println(composition(3)((x: Int) => x + 1)(identity) == composition(3)(identity)((x: Int) => x + 1))
true
```

Alternatively, you can specify the type parameter explicitly to help the compiler infer the right type:

```
println(composition((x: Int) => x + 1, identity[Int], 3) == 
        composition(identity[Int], (x: Int) => x + 1, 3))
```

Comment: Some follow ups if I may: 1.Why is it better to put the parameters into separate parentheses instead of separating them with a comma? 

2.Why this works `def composition[A, B, C](x: A)(f: A => B)(g: B => C)` and this doesn't `def composition[A, B, C](f: A => B)(g: B => C)(x: A)`? 

3.Why when the type of an argument is not deduced correctly, it is interpreted as `Nothing`?

Comment: @octavian 1. Because it helps the Scala compiler infer the proper type. Inference flows from left to right in respect to the parameter list, allowing `x` to be inferred for having type `Int`, and then having `f` be inferred as a `Int => B`. 2. Because the compiler needs help inferring the type of `A`, and as I've mentioned above, inference flows left to right. 3. Because the compiler attempts to find the proper type, and the only one he can infer is a bottom type called `Nothing`, which inherits all Scala types.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: `composition((x: Int) => x + 1, identity)(3)` clearly indicates that `A` and `B` are `Int`. So, why is the compiler having difficulty inferring that identity function is parameterized by `Int`?

Comment: @Samar Because type inference only flows *between* parameter lists, not *inside* them.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the insight. not sure why type inference doesn't / can't flow from left to right *inside* a parameter list.

Comment: @Samar Read [this](http://pchiusano.blogspot.co.il/2011/05/making-most-of-scalas-extremely-limited.html?m=1) for a full overview, including references from Odersky.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: That link was very good reading. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

Below should work. Note the type param for the identity function.

```
assert(composition((x: Int) => x + 1, identity[Int])(3) == composition(identity[Int], (x: Int) => x + 1)(3))
```

Since you have not specified the type param for the identity function, it becomes Nothing and it does not match with the type signature of your method.